# Ubuntu restrict running curl commands in 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, curl, ubuntu-18.04

I have used Udev rule to call a curl command when a specific device connects to my machine. It worked perfectly with Ubuntu 14.04. 
Once I upgrade the machine to Ubuntu 18.04 it stop working.

My udev rule was like this

> ACTION=="add|remove", ENV{PRODUCT}=="acd/3520/*", RUN+="/home/leapset/system/devicemanager/trigger-device-connection.sh"

Inside the script it calls the curl command like below

> curl -X GET
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8080/moxy/rest/device/connectivity/change' -m 2 2>
>   /dev/null &

It always says the curl command timeout although I have increased the timeout to 30 seconds.

What is the change made inside Ubuntu 18.04 which prevent me from using the above implementation?

Comment: Thought of adding this as a question since I didn't find the answer to this in Stack Overflow. I hope the answer to this will help any other person in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the following thread.

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2018-August/041195.html

It seems that restriction to Udev service has prevented us from using the above feature.

The default Service configuration (/lib/systemd/system/udev.service) prevent us from calling any IP

```
[Service]
Type=notify
OOMScoreAdjust=-1000
Sockets=systemd-udevd-control.socket systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
KillMode=mixed
WatchdogSec=3min
TasksMax=infinity
MountFlags=slave
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
RestrictRealtime=yes
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_NETLINK AF_INET AF_INET6
SystemCallArchitectures=native
LockPersonality=yes
IPAddressDeny=any
```

To solve the problem we add another entry to the bottom of the file.

```
IPAddressAllow=127.0.0.1
```

After that Udev able to notify the device plug in to POS